# How do I add and remove a role via a button?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-buttons

I need to ensure that by pressing a button one role is removed and another is added.
This is my code:

```py
class SimpleView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
         self.start_time = None
         self.stop_time = None
         super().__init__(timeout=None)

    @discord.ui.button(label="⬆️", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="1")
    async def entrata(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        orario_it = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Rome'))
        orario = orario_it.strftime('%H:%M')
        
        allowed_role_id = 1215328270443094128
        added_role_id = 1215318583702454352
        removed_role_id = 1215328270443094128
        allowed_role = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, id=allowed_role_id)
        user = interaction.user

        if allowed_role is None or allowed_role not in interaction.user.roles:
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"***Per poter entrare in servizio dei essere in: {allowed_role.mention}!***", ephemeral=True)

        if allowed_role in interaction.user.roles:
            
            SimpleView.start_time = time.time()
            channel = bot.get_channel(1214495527924928522)           
            embed=discord.Embed(color=0x23a559)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://shft.cl/img/c/cdn.discordapp.com-101395680655364460.webp")
            embed.add_field(name="⬆️⬆️", value="", inline=False)                                 #BOTTONE ENTRATA
            embed.add_field(name="NOME:", value=f"{interaction.user.mention}", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="", value="", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="", value="", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="", value="", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="DATA:", value=f"{data}", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="ORARIO:", value=f"{orario}", inline=True)
            embed.set_footer(text="ARMERIA200")
            await user.remove_roles(removed_role_id)
            await user.add_roles(added_role_id)
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"***SEI ENTRATO IN SERVIZIO ALLE: {orario}.***", ephemeral=True)
```

My code doesn't work, what can I do?
It should add and remove a role but it doesn't work, please help me

Comment: added_role = interaction.guild.get_role(added_role_id)
removed_role = interaction.guild.get_role(removed_role_id)
channel = interaction.guild.get_channel(VALID_CHANNEL_ID)
embed.add_field(name="Date", value=f"{orario_it.date()}", inline=True)
await user.remove_roles(removed_role)

Comment: Ensure added_role_id, removed_role_id, and VALID_CHANNEL_ID are replaced with the correct values. Additionally, verify that the orario_it.date() provides the expected date information.

Comment: It doesn't work, from this error:

'discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above code, you have to pass `discord.Role` in the parameter of the `user.add_roles()` (also in `user.remove_roles`), but in the code you are giving role id in the parameter. You will have to get the role by `discord.guild.get_role()`.

You can fix the above problem by using the following code:

```py
class SimpleView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
         self.start_time = None
         self.stop_time = None
         super().__init__(timeout=None)
        
        



    @discord.ui.button(label="⬆️", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="1")
    async def entrata(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
            orario_it = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Rome'))
            orario = orario_it.strftime('%H:%M')
            
            allowed_role_id = 1215328270443094128
            added_role_id = 1215318583702454352
            removed_role_id = 1215328270443094128
            allowed_role = interaction.guild.get_role(allowed_role_id) #here also you can use get_role instead of utils.get
            user = interaction.user

            if allowed_role is None or allowed_role not in interaction.user.roles:
                 await interaction.response.send_message(f"***Per poter entrare in servizio dei essere in: {allowed_role.mention}!***", ephemeral=True)

            if allowed_role in interaction.user.roles:

              
                 SimpleView.start_time = time.time()
                 channel = bot.get_channel(1214495527924928522)           
                 embed=discord.Embed(color=0x23a559)
                 embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://shft.cl/img/c/cdn.discordapp.com-101395680655364460.webp")
                 embed.add_field(name="⬆️⬆️", value="", inline=False)                                 #BOTTONE ENTRATA
                 embed.add_field(name="NOME:", value=f"{interaction.user.mention}", inline=True)
                 embed.add_field(name="", value="", inline=True)
                 embed.add_field(name="", value="", inline=False)
                 embed.add_field(name="", value="", inline=False)
                 embed.add_field(name="DATA:", value=f"{data}", inline=True)
                 embed.add_field(name="ORARIO:", value=f"{orario}", inline=True)
                 embed.set_footer(text="ARMERIA200")
                 added_role = interaction.guild.get_role(added_role_id) #getting the role here
                 removed_role = interaction.guild.get_role(removed_role_id) #getting the role here
                 await user.remove_roles(removed_role) #removing the role here
                 await user.add_roles(added_role) #adding the role here
                 await channel.send(embed=embed)
                 await interaction.response.send_message(f"***SEI ENTRATO IN SERVIZIO ALLE: {orario}.***", ephemeral=True)
```

Also you can use this method instead of `discord.utils.get`.

**Remember: The bot should have `Manage_roles` permission in the server.**

References:

- [discord.guild.get_role()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_role#discord.Guild.get_role)
- [discord.member.add_roles()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=roles#discord.Member.add_roles)
- [discord.role()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=roles#discord.Role)